# CS50x check50 and submit50 dosn't work (Missing enviroment variable CS50_TOKEN)

Tags: visual-studio, cs50

I'm currently doing CS50x and I'm currently on problem set 2. Unfortunately, the Check50 command no longer works. Yesterday it still worked, but since today I always get the same error message:

"Missing environment variable CS50_TOKEN"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXGN8.png)

Even after restarting the codespace several times and closing the browser I used to open the Codespace from, the problem cannot be solved. Nobody on the internet seems to have had this problem either, which surprised me a lot. So unfortunately I don't know how to continue the course.